# location based local notification

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, notifications, uilocalnotification

I was wondering if I can invoke an app based on current location or when the device gets near to certain geographic coordinates. I went through the `UILocalNotification` Class reference. but it work base on date.

regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your app can be notified (even if it's not running) when the device enters a region that you've defined. See [Monitoring Shape-based Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13).

Comment: How would I ensure that notifying the app doesn't directly open the app in the foreground and only sends the local notification?

Comment: @andrewxhill What's your association with SetSDK, and is it a commercial product? Please avoid using comments to promote products.

Comment: I help develop SetSDK which solves exactly this problem It's free to use and you can checkout the onArrival method on the Pods documentation page https://cocoapods.org/pods/SetSDK

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to fire a local notification based on location but you would be able to set one based on local notification. If you are looking to have the app in the background or closed completely and determine if the user entered a certain area then you may be out of luck.

Comment: ya I want to determine location and launch the app weather it is closed completely or in the background. It should be fine if it is in the background, but if it is closed I dont know if that is posible or not.

Comment: I would say it should have been part of the UILocalNotification class

Comment: Yes maybe it should but this is more of Apple's style. I've had an app rejected for using local notifications in ways they didn't intend so by breaking apart functionality at least makes it a little more clear for you not to use their API's in ways they don't want even if its technically correct.

Comment: one thing is if you use private apis, or you use some reserved ui elements in an intended way by apple. other than this I dont think they reject your app based on the way the code is written.

Comment: In my case I used no public API's or reserved UI elements but it was rejected because they didn't feel it was how they intended local notifications to be used. In fairness I don't disagree with their decision.